# Apollo client:codegen how to generate typings for @client directive?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

When I run the following command:

```
apollo client:codegen --target=typescript --config=./apollo.config.js --outputFlat=./graphql.queries.ts
```

> → Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "MySchema": Error:
>   Error in "Loading schema for Merged schema": Error: Unknown directive
>   "client".

This is due to one of my queries containing the `@client` directive:

```
query MyQuery {
    someStuff @client {
        value
    }
}
```

On https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/366
I found out I could specify a --clientSchema attribute to the apollo codegen command for instance:

```
apollo codegen:generate generated \
   --queries=src/components/**/*.tsx \
   --target typescript \
   --schema src/generated/schema.json \ 
   --clientSchema src/state/schema.graphql
```

But I am using an `apollo.config.js` file and I do not find how to specify this clientSchema equivalent into the config file.

I see 2 possible errors:

- either I am not using the @client directive properly
- or there is a missing (removed or undocumented?) support for clientSchema in the apollo.config.js file

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that I would have to add the following line directly in one of the schema.graphql

`directive @client on FIELD` this will overload the AST definition to support the @client directive.

Then writing:

```
query MyQuery {
    someStuff @client {
        value
    }
}
```

Will neither raise an error anymore in my IDE nor throw errors while generating the corresponding queries.ts files.

For info: another thread mentioned adding the line above within the `.graphqlconfig` file like this:

```
{
  "name": "Schema name",
  "schemaPath": "./pathTo/schema.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://localhost:4466",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": false
      }
    },
    "extensions": {
      "customDirectives": [
        "directive @client on FIELD"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But adding it into the .graphqlconfig never worked for me, it would however be a solution to dig…